# What does ICAO database "engine count c" mean?

Tags: icao

In the official [ICAO database](http://www.icao.int/publications/DOC8643/Pages/Search.aspx) 5 aircraft are marked with an engine count C. What is that supposed to mean? Normally engine count is a number (0,1,2,3...).

[image: ICAO]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know the exact ICAO phraseology, but it certainly seems to describe an aircraft that has two engines **combined** to a single driveshaft.

Soloy has trademarked the '[Dual Pac](http://soloy.com/products/fixed-wing/dual-pac/)', a pair of turboprops driving a single shaft through a gearbox. All of the Soloy aircraft there use this powerplant.

[image]

The [Fairey Gannet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fairey_Gannet) was a (super cool) anti-submarine aircraft designed in the late 40s. It was powered by the [Armstrong Siddeley Double Mamba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armstrong_Siddeley_Double_Mamba) which you could argue was the direct predecessor of the Dual Pac, albeit using a presumably very different gearbox to drive the contra-rotating prop. One half of the Double Mamba could be shut down in flight, and both props would continue to be driven:

> The Double Mamba engine could be run with one Mamba stopped to conserve fuel and extend endurance for cruise flight. The contra-rotating propellers meant that when only half of the Double Mamba was running there were no thrust asymmetry problems.

[image]